# How to get the content of prompt() input in a function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I am trying to receive a string from a user to be displayed in the output of a function that is called later in a script. When I try to do this, however, "undefined" is displayed instead of the user-input string.

Below is a shortened example of what I am trying to do:

```js
var Person = function() {};
Person.prototype.initialize = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var Customer = function() {
  this.eat = function(food) {
    var food = prompt("What food are you eating?").innerText;
    console.log(this.name + " is eating " + food);
  }
};

Customer.prototype = new Person();
var me = new Customer();

me.initialize("Jack");
me.eat();
```

How can I make the console output read "Jack is eating `food`"?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? Note:  The parameter "food", where it is coming from?

Comment: `prompt()` has no `innerText`. It just returns a string.

Comment: Hint: where is the `food` parameter coming from?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @Lain, what would I use instead of `innerText`?

Comment: @ttoshiro: Nothing. `var food = prompt("What food are you eating?")` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's supposed to be:

```
var food = prompt("What food are you eating?");
```

`prompt()` just returns the user's input, there isn't a property `innerText`.

[prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)